# Python cannot find package setuptools

Tags: python, package, setuptools

I get the error

```
Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/comp1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 387, in setup_py
import setuptools  # noqa
File "/home/comp1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filter, filterfalse, map
ImportError: No module named 'setuptools.extern.six'
```

even though the same code runs perfectly on a variety of our computers. I do have setuptools installed. I also tried to remove and reinstall it.

EDIT: For some reason, now it works. I don't think we can call it solved, because I did not do anything, but I also don't have the issue anymore.

Comment: did you try `sudo pip install -U setuptools` ?
And also what `which pip` displays?

Comment: It seems like you are using anaconda python. Have you tried normal standard python?

Comment: @nick_gabpe wouldnt use `sudo` for a local version of python

Comment: @nick_gabpe  , which pip3 gives : /home/comp1/anaconda3/envs/mp/bin/pip3  , the sudo pip install I tried and it does not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The python you are using now is `anaconda` distribution. You have to install setuptools for that ditribution.

So use `/home/.../anaconda/lib/python3.5/bin/pip` and that will install it for this particular python.

Comment: how can I do that? and how is it different from 'conda install setuptools'?

Comment: if you run this in terminal `/home/comp1/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/bin/pip install setuptools` it should work. However, it should be the same as conda install, as long as you only have just one anaconda python. Can you show what you get when you put `which conda` in terminal?

Comment: /home/comp1/anaconda3/envs/mp/bin/conda

Comment: alright, seems like you are using a virtual environment mp? you need to activate the environment and then use the pip, or use the pip that is going to be in `.../envs/mp/bin/pip install setuptools` (I suppose, not using conda envs personally) have a  look at https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html

Comment: but I did activate the environment. I was inside the environment when I got the error.

Comment: well it is trying to access the setuptools of another python distribution. just to make sure, with the activated environment, what does `which pip` say?

Comment: maybe it would be safest if you go to the conda GUI and try to install/reinstall on the particular environment from there? have you tried that?

Comment: comp1 is a server so, unfortunately, I cannot access the conda gui.